# Inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have a generic method that checks if an array is sorted. However, when I write in my main `Generic.isSorted(arr)`, I immediately get an error.

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer [] arr = {1,3,8,4,2};
        Generics.isSorted(arr); //error

    }
```

Generic method:

```
    public class Generics()
    {
       public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(T[] arr)
       {
           if (arr == null || arr.length <= 1)
               return true;
           for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
           {    if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[i+1]) > 0)
                { return false;}

           }
           return true;
       }

    }
```

error:

```
  method isSorted in class Generics cannot be applied to given types;
      required: T[]
      found: Integer[]
      reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        inferred: Integer
        upper bound(s): Comparable<? super Integer>
      where T is a type-variable:
        T extends Comparable<? super T> declared in method <T>isSorted(T[])
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: Compiles and runs on Javas 5-7.

Comment: Do you have your own `Integer` class?

Comment: I don't know if these will solve your problem, but **1)** you have syntax problems (e.g. `public class Generics()`), **2)** `<T extends Comparable<T>>` would probably be enough, **3)** you have to loop until `arr.length - 2`, and **4)** an array can contain `null`s, so be aware of NPEs `;)`

Comment: @sp00m It's not the syntax problem. `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` is the right way to do it.

Comment: @rgettman Wouldn't `{1,3,8,4,2};` fail?

Comment: @RohitJain I meant the `public class Generics()` part (an example where new lines in comments would be great)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right.  If there is a custom `Integer` class, then `Integer [] arr = {1,3,8,4,2};` would have a compiler error also, as autoboxing would no longer apply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? extends T>> boolean isSorted(T[] arr)
```

or simply

```
public static <T extends Comparable> boolean isSorted(T[] arr)
```

?

Comment: You've changed the bounds of the type variable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes and to me it seems even more meaningful.

Comment: Edit your answer and explain that.